How to fix export variables from .env in bash wrapped in quotes
This is my
.env.test
S3_READY_MESSAGE="s3 is ready"
NGINX_READY_MESSAGE="nginx is ready"

Bash to output variables
$ echo $(cat ../../../.env.test | grep -o -E '^[^#]+')

output:
S3_READY_MESSAGE="s3 is ready" NGINX_READY_MESSAGE="nginx is ready"

Bash to export variables
export $(cat ../../../.env.test | grep -o -E '^[^#]+')

error
bash: export: `ready"': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `ready"': not a valid identifier


What do you want to do? do you want to set those variables in the current env?

@Inian yes I do

You need a proper dotenv parser for shell. .env files are not compatible with bash semantics.

Why did you roll back my edits? The question is unreadable as originally written.

enable debug mode (set -xv) to see what bash sees; general issue is word/field splitting of the $(cat ... | grep ...) results such that export is fed a bunch of garbage

For this particular sample input you can make use of bash's set -a/+a in conjunction with sourcing .env.test:
$ set -a                                 # enable  auto-export of variable assignments
$ source ../../../.env.test              # alternatively replace 'source' with '.'
$ set +a                                 # disable auto-export of variable assignments

Results:
$ typeset -p S3_READY_MESSAGE NGINX_READY_MESSAGE
declare -x S3_READY_MESSAGE="s3 is ready"
declare -x NGINX_READY_MESSAGE="nginx is ready"


Yeah this worked better. Thankyou

I originally had a solution which exported fine but it doesn't work with quoted content that has spaces.
solution 1 - CON: only works with no spaces in value
.env
var=somethingwasok
var="something with spaces was not ok"

export $(cat ./.env | grep -o -E '^[^#]+' | xargs)

solution 2  CON: Uses eval, so may be deemed unsafe.
(As long as I am doing this manually then I know the file I'm exporting so don't mind using eval in this case.)
#  output .env   | replace each valid line with export | remove comments
#  || export all          ||    val=something               ||
#  \/                     \/    export val=something        \/
eval $(cat ./.env | sed -E 's/^(\w)/export \1/g'         | grep -o -E '^[^#]+')


eval "$(...)" is less buggy than eval $(...). (Adding quotes doesn't fix the major security bugs, but does avoid some correctness issues, insofar as it prevents word-splitting and rejoining from changing whitespace types; prevents globbing from substituting values with filenames; etc).

BTW, both approaches shown here have other problems that have nothing to do with security. For example, single-quoted strings can have literal newlines in them -- variable=' ...newline... line 1 ...newline... line 2 ...newline... ' is a perfectly valid assignment, for example.

@CharlesDuffy Useful points but for now my .env file doesn't have those formats. Though out of interest what would you suggest as foolproof solution. One liner preferred but if not a separate script file to export them all to the shell.

markp-fuso's answer is a solid one, when you have input that's trusted to be valid syntax. Whereas when the .env file is machine-generated or potentially writable by untrusted users, I save them in NUL-delimited form (same format as /proc/*/environ on Linux) and use something akin towhile IFS= read -r -d= key && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do printf -v "$key" %s "$value" && export "$key"; done, with some validation of key if untrusted (making sure the variable name starts with a lower-case character and contains only characters valid in shell variable names prevents a lot of mischief).
